# Using \internal in doxygen to hide internal elements of a structure

Tags: doxygen

In a header file  there is a structure

```
/* temp example structure*/
typedef struct {
        /* @internal */
        char *c;
        /* @internal */
        char *ts;
} j;
```

If the internal elements of  the structure  is not documented, doxygen generates warnings.
But it is necessary to  not document the internal  elements.
So what can be sued.
Tried \internal  but it did not work

Answer (score 2):

`\internal` is used to remove parts of documentation, but use them when you generate internal documentation. You may still want to write documentation for this entries. It is useful when you want to generate full doc for yourself/developers, but generate less detailed (or just omit parts that you can't show because of e.g. NDA) for outside world.

It is used in combination with other doxygen commands, e.g. `/// \internal \defgroup foo` will show this entire group only for internal doc (`INTERNAL_DOCS` in doxygen config). You can also use it for structure fields:

```
struct foo {
   int field0;    /**< Documented field */
   int field1;    /**< \internal only documented for internal doc */
};
```

Field will still be visible in structure doc, but second field will miss any documentation.

You can't define internal block, but you can combine `\internal` with `\defgroup` or `\section`.